# Conky on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: 18.04, conky

Hey I followed this instruction to display my google calendar on desktop in ubuntu 18.04

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/11/how-to-embed-google-calendar-on-your.html

But nothing happens when I do the last step "alt + f2" then type conky inside.

Help pls :)